# Alamofire won't build in empty Swift project using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I am starting a project by creating a blank Single-View app for Swift. Using Cocoapods, I am adding Alamofire as follows:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'TestGauge' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
end

target 'TestGaugeTests' do

end
```

Then, in Terminal I run `pod install`

When returning to XCode, the project fails to build with 1000+ errors generated from Alamofire.

I am running XCode from the workspace file and NOT the project file.

XCode version 6.4

Has anyone had this behavior, or can anyone offer a solution? Have I missed a critical step?

Thanks!

Comment: cant you update the Xcode version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire 3.0 is written in Swift 2.0. Xcode 6.4 does not support Swift 2.0. Change Alamofire version or update your Xcode.

Comment: So, downgrading to Alamofire 2.0 has the same result

Comment: That's weird, even after: `cleaning build folder`, `removing derrivedData`?